# How to uninstall Eclipse C/C++ IDE

Tags: package-management, eclipse

I've looked around for answers to my question but none are what I need. I installed Eclipse  by downloading the package from the Eclipse website and running the following commands:

```
cd /opt
sudo tar -xvzf ~/Downloads/eclipse-jee-2019-09-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
sudo gedit eclipse.desktop
```

And then I added this text to eclipse.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse
Name[en_US]=Eclipse
```

And finally I ran this command:

```
sudo desktop-file-install eclipse.desktop
```

I can't uninstall Eclipse using `apt` or `snap`, so how do I get rid of it?

Comment: the opposite of the way you installed it: remove all the files from `/opt` and delete the `.desktop` file.

Comment: Note - that is a pretty old version of Eclipse. Current versions are here - https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/